# Rails isn't applying daylight saving time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, timezone, dst, dokku

My server's clock is set to London time (I'm currently living in the GMT+0 zone). The output of `timedatectl status` gives me this:

> ```
>   Local time: Mon 2016-05-23 08:13:06 BST   Universal time: Mon 2016-05-23 07:13:06 UTC
>     RTC time: Mon 2016-05-23 07:13:06
>     Timezone: Europe/London (BST, +0100)
>  NTP enabled: yes NTP synchronized: no  RTC in local TZ: no
>   DST active: yes  Last DST change: DST began at
>               Sun 2016-03-27 00:59:59 GMT
>               Sun 2016-03-27 02:00:00 BST  Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
>               Sun 2016-10-30 01:59:59 BST
>               Sun 2016-10-30 01:00:00 GMT
> ```

And in my application.rb file I set the timezone:

```
config.time_zone = 'London'
```

Locally, it works right:

```
Time.now.dst?
# true
Time.now.hour
# 8
```

But in production it doesn't seem that DST is on.

```
Time.now.dst?
# false
Time.now.hour
# 7
```

I am not sure if it's a Rails thing or a server misconfiguration, but for me it seems right.

Comment: Does it give you a different time zone or even a different time (UTC) or is it really just the daylight saving time ?

Comment: have you tried `config.time_zone = 'London'` `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` ?

Comment: Perhaps the date / time on the production is wrong (still in winter)?

Comment: `Time.zone.to_s` returns me (GMT+00:00) London. So time zone seems to be right, but is still in winter time. But a `date` in the server returns me the correct time with DST (with BST, British Summer Time).

Comment: I have tried that @RareFever, but still the same issue. It isn't anyway an AR problem, because it happens even in a *normal* (not AR related) Time object.

Comment: If you reloaded the app server on production after deploying the locale setting, could you try a more thorough restart, e.g. if you used unicorn, could you try `unicorn upgrade` instead of `unicorn update` so that fresh rails code is loaded for sure?

Comment: I have tried even restarting the server with no luck. I restarted also nginx and the app and it's still the same.

Comment: Really you should not rely on default time zone settings.  Instead, only use UTC time from the server, then handle time zone conversion in application logic - not globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this application is running within a docker container, the timezone of the host server may not be applied to the containers. You can probably set the `TZ` environment variable to whatever timezone you'd like and ruby will pick it up.

I highly recommend *not* using non-UTC timezone for your application/database, as it will almost certainly cause problems down the line.

Full disclosure: I am one of the dokku maintainers.

Comment: That worked. I just did `dokku config:set app-name ENV=prod TZ=Europe/London`. Gracias @Jose.